# Reshaping values before plotting scatter plot

Tags: python, reshape, scatter-plot

I was studying python and came across something I'm not sure about. Here is the data frame.

```
 year     totalprod
0   1998  5.105093e+06
1   1999  4.706674e+06
2   2000  5.106000e+06
3   2001  4.221545e+06
4   2002  3.892386e+06
5   2003  4.122091e+06
6   2004  4.456805e+06
7   2005  4.243146e+06
8   2006  3.761902e+06
9   2007  3.600512e+06
10  2008  3.974927e+06
11  2009  3.626700e+06
12  2010  4.382350e+06
13  2011  3.680025e+06
14  2012  3.522675e+06
```

Before performing the scatter plot, the course was telling me to reshape x values, which are years.

Here is the code

```
X = prod_per_year['year']
X = X.values.reshape(-1,1)

y = prod_per_year['totalprod']

plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.show()
```

Why do we have to reshape before plotting? Aren't the values the same?

Comment: Print the values before and after reshaping to see the difference

Comment: I have, and the only difference is that each value is in a sub-list.

Comment: Can you please share your output so we can see it as well.